# MPI gives strange character in process 0 when using strcat

Tags: character, mpi, strcat

I am doing a project to find how frequency each item meet each other in 5 group. the default items are 10, using command mpirun -n 10 ./a.out gave correct results except the result in process 0.
When I use the strcat to append string, only the process 0 add the strange character '4' in the end of the code. 
result is here:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyCTZ.jpg)

The problem is in the codes:

```
if(indexListofEachItem[rank][j] == indexListofEachItem[i+1][k])
            {
                char ctemp[1];
                ctemp[0] = indexListofEachItem[i+1][k];
                strcat(frequence[n], ctemp); 
                count[n]++;
            }
```

Here are the full codes:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <mpi.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int gen_val,first_val, second_val, temp, rank,proc_size;
int allItem = 0;
int n = 0;
int listofAllItem[50];
char indexListofEachItem[50][50];
bool found = false;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_size);
int numbOfItem = 5 ;
int val[5][5] ={5,4,6,7,8,
                5,0,4,9,8,
                1,6,2,3,9,
                3,7,1,0,5,
                4,9,8,0,2};
int count[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int firstNum[50];
int secondNum[50];
char frequence[9][50] = {0};
int allListItem[5];
int index;int outofrangeVal = 10;
for(int i= 0; i< 5;i++)
{
    if(rank == i)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for(int ii = 0 ; ii < numbOfItem ; ii++)
            storedVal[ii] = outofrangeVal;
        printf("process %d: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",rank, val[rank][0], val[rank][1], val[rank][2],val[rank][3], val[rank][4]);
        if(rank != 0)
            MPI_Send(val[rank], 5, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
if(rank == 0)
{
    index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        listofAllItem[i] = val[0][i];
        sprintf(indexListofEachItem[i],"%d", index);
        allItem++;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(allListItem, 5, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        index = i;
        char c[5];
        sprintf(c, "%d", i);
        for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < allItem; j++)
                if(allListItem[k] == listofAllItem[j])
                {
                    strcat(indexListofEachItem[j], c);
                    found = true;
                } 
            if(found == false)
            {
                listofAllItem[allItem] = allListItem[k];
                strcpy(indexListofEachItem[allItem], c);
                allItem++;
            }
            found = false;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < proc_size - 1; i++)
        for(int j = i+1; j< proc_size; j++)
        {
            if(listofAllItem[i] > listofAllItem[j])
            {
                int temp = listofAllItem[j];
                listofAllItem[j] = listofAllItem[i];
                listofAllItem[i] = temp;
                char ctemp[50];
                strcpy(ctemp, indexListofEachItem[j]);
                strcpy(indexListofEachItem[j],indexListofEachItem[i]);
                strcpy(indexListofEachItem[i],ctemp);
            }
        }
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(listofAllItem, 10, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(indexListofEachItem, 2500, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&allItem, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
n = 0;
for(int r = 0 ; r < proc_size; r++)
if(r == rank)
{
for(int i = rank; i < proc_size-1; i++)
{
    firstNum[n] = listofAllItem[rank];
    secondNum[n] = listofAllItem[i+1];
    for(int j = 0 ; j < strlen(indexListofEachItem[rank]); j++)
    {

        for(int k = 0; k < strlen(indexListofEachItem[i+1]); k++)
        {
            if(indexListofEachItem[rank][j] == indexListofEachItem[i+1][k])
            {
                char ctemp[1];
                ctemp[0] = indexListofEachItem[i+1][k];
                strcat(frequence[n], ctemp);
                count[n]++;
            }
        }

    }
    n++;
}
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  

n = sizeof(secondNum)/sizeof(secondNum[0]);
int i = 0;
if(rank != proc_size-1)
do
{
    printf("rank %d, %d and %d appear %d times in index %s", rank, firstNum[i],secondNum[i],count[i], frequence[i]);
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}while(i< n && secondNum[i]!= 0);
printf("\n");
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: How long is the resulting string, does it overflow the definition? Strcat is dangerous to use and should be avoided.

Comment: In the future, all the string will be extended, that is why I just declare them as 50 elements. I didnt see any append string funcfion except this one.

Comment: What std library/os/compiler is this? You should have normally `strncat`. If you dynamically want to allocate/extend strings you should not declare them statically.

Comment: I compiled it under linux environment. For strncat, how can I only append 1 character from the source string to dest string? I do the static to test my algorithm before upgrade the codes

Comment: Strncat and Strcat work the same, you just specify the maximum length so Strncat will abort instead of overwrite. But honestly you might need to do more here, since you need to handle the terminating null, so for tests just make sure you do not overflow the 50 char strings (incl \0 terminator). If you don't, your issue might be somewhere else. (I am not sure how MPI and array initialisation work together)

Comment: I am sure it didnt exceed the array, coz as in the screenshot you see that there is only 9 elements. The problem is i printf ctemp and it gavd correct answer, but when I strcat to destination, it automatically added character '4' in the end of the string. Other processes give perfect answer, only process 0 gave this problem. I have no ideas where the '=' comes from

Comment: I did not try to understand the screenshot, but if you say so, then it's probably a initilisation/concurrency issue. I have no idea about those in MPI.

Comment: Oh another thing, you cannot append char[1] with a missing \0, if it is always 1 character you can use `strncat(frequence[n], demo, 1)` or `char ctemp[2]; ctemp[1] = '\0';`

Comment: Better use the latter to keep `frequence` null-terminated.

Comment: @eckes: previously, I used ctemp in char var, not char array and it still gave the same error. Thank you, I will try strncat to see if there is any differences

Comment: @Gilles: how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to append `\0` terminated strings, only:

```
    char ctemp[2];
    ctemp[1] = ’\0';
    ctemp[0] = indexListofEachItem[i+1][k];
    //if (strlen(frequence[n]) > 48) abort 
    strncat(frequence[n], ctemp, 2);
```

Comment: BTW if this is supposed to be high speed cost not using string functionality might be better (strcat needs to iterate the whole existing string). If it is always single characters using `frequence[n][++count[n]]` (plus memset) might be better)

Comment: in that case, do not forget to null-terminate `frequence` at the end.